# Check if a table field’s column has a value

Tags: table-field

I am using a table field to display credits on a portfolio page.
The table field has three columns: `hva`, `hvem` and `url`.

The `url` should be optional and I want to set up an if statement showing it as a link if it has a value. Is this possible using the table field?

Also, the table field can have multiple rows.

I have tried to set up an if for `row.url` to see if has a value. And an else for when there is no URL.

```
{% if entry.credits|length %}
    {% for row in entry.credits %}
        {% if row.url == 0 %}
            <li><span class="bold">{{ row.hva }}:</span> <a href="{{ row.url }}">{{ row.hvem }}</a></li>
        {% else %}
            <li><span class="bold">{{ row.hva }}:</span> {{ row.hvem }}</li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close...

Chaning this:

```
{% if row.url == 0 %}
```

to this:

```
{% if row.url|length %}
```

should do it for you.

Comment: Thanks Brad! Worked like a charm :)